# Embedding SQL Server CE database into a C# application

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I'm developing a program which uses SQL Server Compact Edition for processing data. We all know that this creates a `.sdf` file in output (SQL Server CE database File).

My question is if there is anyway to embed this `.sdf` file into the executable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for that to be possible it would need to be read only I suppose. Are you asking because you want to distribute only the exe? One way I can imagine is to put the sdf inside as a "filestream" ressource, then when your application runs the first thing is to load the filestream from the assembly and write it to a temp.sdf and load that one

Answer (score 1):

You could add the `.sdf` file to a Resources File `.resx` and then when your application starts you can just copy it out of your Resources and create it, if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: If you mean that application do this for the first time I think it won't be a good way, But if you mean that application Extract it on load and Update resource file on exit, is it possible?? as Cilvic said I think it's read-only

Comment: @Amir, are you trying to do this so you only have one exe to distribute? Or do you physically want the db to be part of the exe?

Comment: To tell you the truth both of'em. First one to be more portable and second one for more security

Comment: @Amir, well the first part is possible, second part isn't and if you worried about security then all you need to do is set a username and password on your database. There are other more advanced features you can look at for database security but I don't think you should worry about that. Let the database handle the encryption and security, you just worry about the programming. :)